# HttpPostedFileBase error (file object was null)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My html file index.cshtml is like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller is like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase myfile)
        {
            string currentdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            myfile.SaveAs(currentdir + "\\" + myfile.FileName);

            return View();
        }
    }
```

And the error occurred when I posted a file. It told myfile object was null. Please help fixing this. Thx so much !

Comment: Using enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Answer (score 2):

Add enctype attribute in form tag like below,

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```